# Stuck between a wall and a hard place

Tags: drywall

I am making a hole for a bracket to support a floating shelf. It’s Sheetrock. After I pass through the Sheetrock I hit something hard that even with a Hammer drill I cannot pierce.

Could it be a steel support beam? Could it be I need a special drill bit for the hammer drill? Could it be I’m not pushing hard enough?

I’m in a condominium by the way. Also, the stud buddy doesn’t show anything at that point.

[image]

Comment: Shine a light in the hole, what do you see?

Comment: Use a magnet to determine if it is steel

Comment: Actually been doing that. After tons of drilling only a very slight indentation. Can’t tell what it is but doesn’t look like steel. Hard to tell.

Comment: If it is steel, you don't want to put a hole through it. Not even a small one. In commercial settings, they _clamp_ pipe/conduit hangars to the I-beams and don't drill and bolt through them.

Comment: thank you for the input.

Comment: I’m using the stud buddy and getting no reaction so I don’t think it’s steel

Comment: Holy crap!   You are drilling into a wall and have no idea what you are hitting? You could do a lot of damage and possible personal injury.  Open up the sheetrock and figure out what you're dealing with.  Sorry to be so emphatic, but please, be more careful.

Comment: I agree with George you could be drilling into a raceway or water pipe depending on the age or even a “nail plate” that is to prevent nail damage to whatever is under the plate. I have seen people drill into electrical conduit it might just turn your drill bit into a welding rod as the power for the building goes dark (very expensive to repair).